# Livecode Datagrid Copy and Paste

Tags: livecode

Using the livecode `datagrid`, does `copy` and `paste` from one cell to another possible? Something like the spreadsheet capability.

Currently, we need to double click the cell and copy its text from one cell to another non-empty cell.

Update: This is now working. I got below code from [here](http://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=23827)

`on commandKeyDown k
  switch k
  case "c"
     copy
     break
  case "v"
     paste
     break
  default
    pass commandKeyDown
  end switch
end commandKeyDown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if cell editing is enabled, you will find that a DataGrid acts very much like a spreadsheet. Just pretend you are in Excel, and use the DataGrid the same way. So if you copy some portion of data in a "cell", you may set the insertion point at any point in any other "cell". Then just paste as usual.

This is all doable under script control, where you can extract the contents of the DataGrid via the `dgText` or the `dgData`, manipulate that data in the clear or as an array, and then reset that property with the new information.